# what does 차 meam (e.g. 11년 차)

Tags: meaning

i chanced upon a phrase 나는 **11 년 차** 공황장애 환자다 (i've been suffering from panic disorder for 11 years)

i take it **차** can be translated as "lasting for... "

so, did i get it right that the whole phrase literally means "i suffer from panic disorder that has lasted for 11 years"?

is there any difference between **동안** and **차** besides the construction?

Answer (score 1):

https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/26336806b6ea4341b39cc968fb5f3b6f

This is the definition of the word: 4.  ((일정한 기간을 나타내는 명사구 뒤에 쓰여)) 주기나 경과의 해당 시기를 나타내는 말.

차 is more like "~th" in English. So "11년 차" is closer to "11th year" rather than "for 11 years" or "lasting 11 years." Even though you may translate it that way to make it sound smoother.

동안 is more like "for a given time". So 11년 동안 would be "for 11 years."

I hope this helped!